# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database my server host provides & I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '**USERNAME**'@'pool-100-16-152-15.bltmmd.fios.verizon.net' (using password: YES)
```

The following is my code:

```
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'REMOVED';
/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'REMOVED';
/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'REMOVED';

function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password){
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=unturned", $username, $password);
    return $dbh;
}

try {
    $dbh = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
    echo 'Connected to database';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The user I have set up has permissions to all databases & all actions...

I use creeperhost to host an unturned server and I used the MySQL database they provide, I am not having errors on my sever run from there but when I use the website on my personal rig it gives me this error.

Comment: You've probably only granted access to `username@localhost`, not `username@%`. So you can't use the database remotely until you add additional grants.

Comment: @Barmar Its username@IP not localhost, do you know how to add these grants?

Comment: Use `SHOW GRANTS FOR username@IP`, then copy all those grants to `username@%.bltmmd.fios.verizon.net`.

Comment: @Barmar There is no user under `username@%.bltmmd.fios.verizon.net`, I think my ISP is blocking me from querying the database, do you know if this can happen?

Comment: I know, you have to create the user first.

Comment: The error you're getting is not from the ISP blocking you, it's from the database.

Comment: This is basic database administration.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I am just getting into SQL through PHP because I'm 15, I did what you said and it worked, I thank you very much, If you want to see my first website as a 15 year old its here, www.GangsRP.com - Again I thank you very much.